# What does calling Tk() actually do?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I was brushing up on Tkinter when I looked upon a minimal example from the [NMT Tkinter 8.5 Reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/minimal-app.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, master=None):    
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):    
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit',command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid()

app = Application()
app.master.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()
```

It's all well and good, until I notice that the `Tk` class isn't being initialized. In other online reference material I could find ([Python's Library Reference](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tkinter.html?highlight=tkinter#a-simple-hello-world-program), [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-tkinter.htm), [TkDocs](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html)), there's usually a call to `root = tk.Tk()`, from which the rest of the examples are built upon. I also didn't see any sort of reference to the `Tk` class initialization anywhere on the NMT's reference.

The information I could get regarding the `Tk` class is also vague, with the Python Reference only listing it as a "toplevel widget ... which usually is the main window of an application". Lastly, if I replace the last lines in the snippet I presented earlier:

```
root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)
```

The program would run as well as it did before. With all this in mind, what I'm interested in knowing is:

- What does calling `root = tk.Tk()` actually do (as in, what gets initialized) and why can the previous snippet work without it?
- Would I run into any pitfalls or limitations if I don't call `Tk()` and just built my application around the `Frame` class?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Tkinter works by starting a tcl/tk interpreter under the covers, and then translating tkinter commands into tcl/tk commands. The main window and this interpreter are intrinsically linked, and both are required for a tkinter application to work.

Creating an instance of `Tk` initializes this interpreter and creates the root window. If you don't explicitly initialize it, one will be implicitly created when you create your first widget.

I don't think there are any pitfalls by not initializing it yourself, but as the zen of python states, "explicit is better than implicit". Your code will be slightly easier to understand if you explicitly create the instance of `Tk`. It will, for instance, prevent other people from asking the same question about your code that you just asked about this other code.

Answer (score 9):

[Bryan Oakley's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24739730/2651145) answer is spot on. Creating a widget will *implicitly* create an instance of the tcl/tk interpreter. I would, however, like to add some pieces of code, to better understand how Tk is implicitly created.

Whenever a Widget object is created (whether it is a Frame or a Button or even a ttk-based widget), the `BaseWidget` class' `__init__` method is called, which in turn calls the  `_setup` method. Here is a snippet of the relevant part:

```py
def _setup(self, master, cnf):
    """Internal function. Sets up information about children."""
    if _support_default_root:
        global _default_root
        if not master:
            if not _default_root:
                _default_root = Tk()
            master = _default_root
    self.master = master
    self.tk = master.tk
```

Both `_support_default_root` and `_default_root` are global variables, declared in lines 132-133 of the `__init__.py` file in the `tkinter` package. They are initialized to the following values:

```py
_support_default_root = 1
_default_root = None
```

This means that, if `master` isn't provided, and if an interpreter wasn't already created, an instance of `Tk` gets created and assigned as the default root for all future widgets.

There is also something interesting when creating an instance of the `Tk` class. The following snippet comes from the `Tk._loadtk` method:

```py
if _support_default_root and not _default_root:
    _default_root = self
```

Which means that, regardless of how the `Tk` class gets initialized, it is always set up as the default root.