# Why isn't the fade in animation working but the fade out animation works?

Tags: python, animation, tkinter, fadein, fadeout

I am new to python and I came up with this idea on how to make a simple fade animation in **python using tkinter and the time module**. I have defined two animations for the program: one to fade in and the other one to fade out. The fade out animation works perfectly and exactly how I want it to be, however, the fade in animation does not work at all. The program pretty much doesn't show up until the while loop is finished. Am I doing something wrong or is it just impossible to create a fade in effect in python tkinter?
Here is my code snippet:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
transparency = 0
while transparency <= 1:
    transparency += 0.1
    root.wm_attributes("-alpha", transparency)
    time.sleep(0.03)


def fade():
    t = 1
    while t > 0:
        t -= 0.1
        root.wm_attributes("-alpha", t)
        time.sleep(0.03)
    root.destroy()


btn = Button(root, text='fade exit', command=fade).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The simple fix is adding `root.update()` before `time.sleep(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `while` loops and `time`, use `after(millis, function)` and recursion.

**bonuses:**

- use the function arguments to customize the fade effect and behavior
- this will not block the root from updating
- everything is encapsulated
- these functions can be used on any `Toplevel` window
- `applyFades` manages everything in one call

If you absolutely need to attach these features to a `Button`, simply assign the `command` argument like this: `command=lambda: fadeOut(root)`.

window.py

```
''' Fade In
    @window ~ the window to affect
    @millis ~ the amount of milliseconds to wait before next recursion
    @inc    ~ the amount to increment alpha on each recursion
'''
def fadeIn(window, millis:int=50, inc:float=0.1):
    alpha = float(window.attributes('-alpha')) + inc
    window.attributes('-alpha', alpha)
    if alpha < 1:
        window.after(millis, lambda: fadeIn(window, millis, inc))
    else:
        window.attributes('-alpha', 1.0)


''' Fade Out
    @window, @millis ~ see: Fade In
    @dec     ~ the amount to decrement alpha on each recursion
    @destroy ~ True|False destroy the window when effect is complete
'''
def fadeOut(window, millis:int=50, dec:float=0.1, destroy:bool=True):
    alpha = float(window.attributes('-alpha')) - dec
    window.attributes('-alpha', alpha)
    if alpha > 0:
        window.after(millis, lambda: fadeOut(window, millis, dec, destroy))
    else:
        window.attributes('-alpha', 0.0)
        if destroy:
            window.destroy()
            
            
''' Assign All Fades In One Call
    @window, @millis, @inc  ~ see: Fade In
    @dec, @destroy          ~ see: Fade Out
    @close ~ True|False add fadeOut effect to window close button
'''
def applyFades(window, millis:int=50, inc:float=0.1, dec:float=0.1, destroy:bool=True, close:bool=True):
    window.attributes('-alpha', 0.0)
    window.after(millis, lambda: fadeIn(window, millis, inc))
    if close:
        window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: fadeOut(window, millis, dec, destroy))
```

main.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import window as win
        
  
root = tk.Tk()

win.applyFades(root) 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, @Michael! Hope you are having a great day! Thank you so much for the code snippet! It worked out for me! However, I really want to know why my code did not work. Was it solely because I used time.sleep or my entire algorithm is wrong? I would really like to know. Thanks!

Comment: @Omid Ketabollahi Yes. The while loop was stopping mainloop from running til it was done. Essentially, you were blocking the gui from updating. Use `after()` when you need to `sleep`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what you script does. At the beginning [`root = Tk()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24739730/3044825) is assigned which starts a tcl/tk interpreter and creates a root window. Then it controls its opacity attribute to fade in. After that a Button widget is placed on the root window which has these properties:

- a text 'fade exit' is written on the top on the widget
- it waits for a mouse click and after it controls opacity attribute of a root window to fade out.

Finally, [`root.mainloop()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158947/3044825) is a substitute for

```
while True:
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
```

You might pay attention that 'fade in' button is being created at the moment your root window is not updated. This is a reason why you're not able to see actual fade in.

**Solution 1.** Updating root window after each sample of fading in:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

def fade():
    t = 1
    while t > 0:
        t -= 0.1
        root.wm_attributes("-alpha", t)
        time.sleep(0.03)
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()
transparency = 0
btn = Button(root, text='fade in', command=fade)
btn.pack()

while transparency <= 1:
    transparency += 0.1
    root.wm_attributes("-alpha", transparency)
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)

btn.configure(text='fade exit') #I guess no new button is needed and text should be replaced only
root.mainloop()
```

**Solution 2.** It's more typical not to use `tkinter` in combination with `time` and use `after` method. Check out Michael's answer.